# VS2022 No items in toolbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, .net-core

Something has happened to my VS 2022 installation. When I open a WinForms solution (Net6.0), there are no items in the toolbox.

The project settings contain

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>Flasher-UI</RootNamespace>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <PublishUrl>***</PublishUrl>
    <Install>true</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
    <UpdateEnabled>false</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
    <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
    <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
    <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <ApplicationRevision>4</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>2.1.0.0</ApplicationVersion>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <PublishWizardCompleted>true</PublishWizardCompleted>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>true</ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
  </PropertyGroup>
...
```

I have tried all the suggestions I have found when searching. These include

- Toolbox->Reset
- Toolbox->Choose items, Reset
- Updated VS to latest level (17.3.4)

I have loaded a WPF solution and there the toolbox is filled normally.

I tried another WinForms solution which uses .Net Framework 3.5 and again the toolbox is filled.

The project did work normally until recently. I can only assume that I have changed something in the project settings but I don't know what that might be.

UPDATE

- updated to latest level
- problem occurs with new .Net 6 Winforms app too
- deleted .vs folder in existing solution

SOLUTION

Repair the VS installation and reboot.

Comment: Have you deleted ALL the solution's temporary files (while Visual Studio is closed)? Particularly the ".vs" folder.

Comment: If you create a brand new .Net 6 Winforms application (in a different solution), does it still not show any toolbox items?

Comment: Is this happening on a new project ? If not, try moving the `.vs` (hidden) folder out of your solution directory. If it is try repairing VS

Comment: There was a (huge) issue with this, mainly in VB.Net Projects, after the big 17.3.0 update. Then, after 4 updates in 12 days, it has been solved. You can try to clean and rebuild the Solution, exit VS, delete the hidden `.vs` folder in the Solution's main folder, restart, rinse and repeat if it doesn't work immediately

Comment: Sounds like vs2022 bugs strike again. Did you get latest VS update? Which BTW does not guarantee anything

Comment: I find that the toolbox only displays controls when I click on or have in focus a window that supports them e.g., XAML page for WPF.

Comment: Update 17.3.5 available now, it further fixes the current *glitches* of the Windows Forms Designer. Replaces `Devenv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My vs2022 had the same problem in the last update, but after I `repaired` it through the `installer`, it was back to normal.

[image]